# Spring map Enum in @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my controller I made an endpoint that allows status change:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{ids}" + "/" + "status", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> changeStatus(@PathVariable final List<Integer> ids,
                                         @NotNull @RequestBody final String status) {
    deviceService.updateStatus(ids, status);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

And enum looks like this:

```
public enum DeviceStatus {
    ACTIVE, INACTIVE, DELETED, ARCHIVED;

    @JsonCreator
    public static DeviceStatus parseWithValidation(String status) {
        final String upperCaseStatus = status.toUpperCase();
        if (exists(upperCaseStatus)) {
            return DeviceStatus.valueOf(upperCaseStatus);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedStatusException();
        }
    }

    private static boolean exists(final String upperCaseStatus) {
        return Arrays.stream(values()).anyMatch(c -> c.name().equals(upperCaseStatus));
    }
}
```

But `Device` domain object has a field `Status` of type `DeviceStatus`, so how should change status:

```
public void updateStatus(final List<Integer> ids, final String status) {
        getByIds(ids).forEach(device -> {
            device.setStatus(status);
            update(device);
        });
    }
```

But there is a problem with `device.setStatus(status);`. I can use `parseWithValidation` but it doesn't make sense, because it is already done. Someone gives me `{"status":"INACTIVE"}` How should I parse this enum ?

Comment: I think you should read the code of Enum.valueOf ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: updated see comments

---

Your *request body* is an object with one field named `status` of type `DeviceStatus`, so you can probably use your `Device` class

So:

```
class Device {
    // will be validated in the controller
    private String status;
    // getter, setter, etc
}

// with:

public enum DeviceStatus {
    ACTIVE, INACTIVE, DELETED, ARCHIVED;
}
```

and `@RequestBody Foo foo` in the controller method signature:

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> changeStatus(@PathVariable final List<Integer> ids, @NotNull @RequestBody final Device device) {
    try {
        deviceService.updateStatus(ids, DeviceStatus.valueOf(device.getStatus()));
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        // throw some custom exception. device.getStatus() was invalid
    } catch(NullPointerException ex) {
        // throw some custom exception. device.getStatus() was null
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: so `parseWithValidation` and `@JsonCreate` are  unnecessary ? What wil happen if someone put a status that doesn't exist in enum ?

Comment: see [Enum#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) (=> `IllegalArgumentException`)

Comment: Is it possible to use my own exception ?

Comment: maybe you should use some @ExceptionHandler instead, see https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc but I will edit for a solution with a custom exception